# Substring inside xpath on header value in Apache Camel / Spring DSL

Tags: java, xml, spring, xpath, apache-camel

I've flow like this and my problem is that I'm getting the wrong value on the second header:

```
                           <when>                       
                           <xpath>//kred:assigment_GetRq/nrb</xpath>
                            <setHeader headerName="nrbPE">
                                <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">//kred:assigment_GetRq/nrb/text()</xpath>
                            </setHeader>
                            <setHeader headerName="subNrbPE">
                                <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">substring(${headers.nrbPE}, 3, 6)</xpath>
                            </setHeader>
                            <setHeader headerName="kod">
                                <simple>${properties:apiEsb.assigment.bpCode}</simple>
                            </setHeader>
                            <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="header nrb: ${headers.nrbPE}"/>
                            <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="header subNrb: ${headers.subNrbPE}"/>
                            <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="Property: ${headers.kod}"/>
                            <choice>
                                <when>
                                    <xpath>${headers.subNrbPE} = ${headers.kod}</xpath>
                                    <process ref="createDetailSectionProc" />
                                </when>
                                <otherwise>
                                    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="otherwise"/>
                                </otherwise>
                                </choice>
                            </when>
```

Logs:

```
08:26:47,067 | INFO  | Esb| Assigment_Get    |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | header nrb: 99999999
08:26:47,067 | INFO  | Esb| Assigfment_Get    |  | 68 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0.fuse-03-01 | header subNrb: ass ja
```

I don't understand what is wrong with syntax cause the second value should be 9999, but I see that substring is making on (class java...) Could you tell me where I made a mistake? I need to compare  this substring value with property value in some logic statement in Camel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use below syntax:

```
<setHeader headerName="subNrbPE">
   <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">substring($in:nrbPE, 3, 4)</xpath>
</setHeader>
```

because XPath [substring](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring) takes

> fn:substring(sourceString, startingLoc, length)

So if you want to have 4 digits, you need to specify starting position (3) and how many chars you want (4).

Also comparison should be changed to:

```
<simple>${headers.subNrbPE} == ${headers.kod}</simple>
```